# How to make the Post Author name fixed as "Editorial Staff" even if there are multiple authors?

Tags: posts, author, author-template

I want the Post author's name to be fixed as "Editorial Staff" and not show the multiple authors' names. Can anyone assist me please?

Comment: This is difficult to properly assist with unless you can provide more information - it can absolutely be done, but are you on a child theme, are you on a custom theme, a third-party theme that you can't edit... ...can you write PHP, JS?  Is it for ALL authors or just some authors?  If you want assistance, be descriptive.

Comment: I am learning wp and testing on Astra Theme's child theme. And I can't write PHP or JS. I wanted it for all authors.

Comment: So the problem is that you will need to either hook into some sort of action, filter or hook that Astra provides, or you'll have to write your own JS to change the display.  Themes like Astra are great in that they make it easy to use WP, but if you haven't set things up from the start to use as a 'developer', you can find yourself hitting a lot of dead ends or having to write unnecessarily complex codes for a very simple solution.  Have you reached out to the Astra support team to ask them for a potential solution?

Comment: No, I haven't reached out to the Astra team yet because they take longer to respond to the tickets.